# cvCapture and directshow

Tags: c++, video, opencv, directshow

I need to read an avi file and process data from it in OpenCV.

Should I use cvCapture or directshow?

What are the criterions?

What are the advantages of each?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding OpenCV, the most obvious advantages are:

- It provides a cross-platform solution for retrieving frames from the camera;
- [cvCapture](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cvcapture) is incredibly easy to use.

Disadvantages:

- OpenCV supports a smaller amount of camera devices.

Check [cv::VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) if you want to use the C++ interface of OpenCV.

If you will use OpenCV to process data, it makes no sense to add DirectShow to your project just to grab frames from the camera if your camera is supported by OpenCV.